# Concatenate gzipped files with Python, on Windows

Tags: python, gzip, concatenation

Is there a memory-efficient way to concatenate gzipped files, using Python, on Windows, without decompressing them?

According to a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005155/50065), it should be as simple as:

```
cat file1.gz file2.gz file3.gz > allfiles.gz
```

but how do I do this with Python, on Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just keep writing to the same file.

```
with open(..., 'wb') as wfp:
  for fn in filenames:
    with open(fn, 'rb') as rfp:
      shutil.copyfileobj(rfp, wfp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need python to copy many files to one. You can use standard Windows "Copy" for this:

```
copy file1.gz /b + file2.gz /b + file3.gz /b allfiles.gz
```

Or, simply:

```
copy *.gz /b allfiles.gz
```

But, if you wish to use Python, Ignacio's answer is a better option.

Comment: You forgot the `+`s and the `/b`s.

Comment: You have an extraneous `+` before `allfiles.gz` that will cause `file1.gz` to get overwritten.  
"If you omit Destination, the files are combined and stored under the name of the first file in the list."  
  
[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy)

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the attention to detail. Than said, understanding the meaning of /b before and after files is really difficult to understand..

Answer (score 1):

If

```
cat file1.gz file2.gz file3.gz > allfiles.gz
```

works, then this should work too:

```
fileList = ['file1.gz', 'file2.gz', 'file3.gz']
destFilename = 'allfiles.gz'

bufferSize = 8  # Adjust this according to how "memory efficient" you need the program to be.

with open(destFilename, 'wb') as destFile:
    for fileName in fileList:
        with open(fileName, 'rb') as sourceFile:
            chunk = True
            while chunk:
                chunk = sourceFile.read(bufferSize)
                destFile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: This will truncate input files to the size of the buffer.

Comment: Whoops, you're right - forgot the while loop to get entire file - edited, thanks.

Comment: The inner loop can be shortened to `for chunk in iter(lambda: sourceFile.read(bufferSize), ''): destFile.write(chunk)`. Also, please bear in mind that PEP 8 recommends names_with_underscores in preference to camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, gzipped files can be directly concatenated via the `cat` CL command, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an obvious python command to do this (in the standard library `gzip` anyways). However, I only looked briefly. There are probably libraries out there to accomplish this.

Nonetheless, a way to accomplish this using the standard library is to call `cat` using `subprocess`:

```
from subprocess import check_call
command = "cat {} {} > {}".format(file1_path, file2_path, output_name)
check_call(command.split())  # Check call takes a list
```

To generalize this to arbitrary numbers of inputs, you can do:

```
inputs = ['input1', 'input2', ... 'input9001']
output_name = 'output.gz'

command = "".join(['cat ', '{} ' * len(inputs), '> {out}'])
_call_ = command.format(*inputs, out=output_name).split()

check_call(_call_)
```

I hope that is helpful to someone.