# Can I append to a compressed stream with pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, gzip

I know that by passing the `compression='gzip'` argument to `pd.to_csv()` I can save a DataFrame into a compressed CSV file.

```
my_df.to_csv('my_file_name.csv', compression='gzip')
```

I also know that if I want to *append* a DataFrame to the end of an existing CSV file I can use `mode='a'`, like so

```
my_df.to_csv('my_file_name.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

But what if I want to append a DataFrame to the end of a compressed CSV file? Is that even possible? I tried to do so with

```
my_df.to_csv('my_file_name.csv', mode='a', index=False, compression='gzip')
```

But the resulting CSV was not compressed, albeit in fine condition.

---

This question is motivated by my processing of a large CSV file with Pandas. I need to produce compressed CSV output, and am processing the CSV file in chunks into a DataFrame so that I don't run into a MemoryError. Hence, the most seemingly logical thing for me to do is to append each output DataFrame chunk together into one compressed zip file.

I am using Python 3.4 and Pandas 0.16.1.

Comment: Appending a gzipped data frame works for me in pandas 0.18.1. You can also just [concatenate gzipped files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005114/fast-concatenation-of-multiple-gzip-files).

Answer (score 3):

Up-to-date answer: worked for me with pandas 1.2.4

Code:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', mode='a', compression='gzip')
new_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', compression='gzip')

df.shape[0] # 1x
new_df.shape[0] # 2x
```

Comment: yea, but it's not compressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('my_file_name.csv.gz', 'a') as compressed_file:
    df.to_csv(compressed_file, index=False)
```

since pandas `.to_csv` method accepts a path or a file-like object.

Comment: Does not work with python 3.6.9, pandas 0.25.3: `TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: How was this resolved. I am getting the same error.

Comment: `compressed_file.write(df.to_csv().encode())` now works.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer does not seem to work anymore. When `df.to_csv()` is handed no path or file-like object it returns the dataframe as string. This can be encoded and written to the gzip file.

```
import gzip

with gzip.open('my_file_name.csv.gz', 'a') as compressed_file:
    compressed_file.write(df.to_csv().encode())
```