# IO::Uncompress::Gunzip stops after first "original" gzipped file inside "concatenated" gzipped file

Tags: bash, perl, gzip

In `bash`, you can concatenate gzipped files and the result is a valid gzipped file. As far as I recall, I have always been able to treat these "concatenated" gzipped files as normal gzipped files (my example code from link above):

```
echo 'Hello world!' > hello.txt
echo 'Howdy world!' > howdy.txt
gzip hello.txt 
gzip howdy.txt

cat hello.txt.gz howdy.txt.gz > greetings.txt.gz

gunzip greetings.txt.gz

cat greetings.txt
```

Which outputs

```
Hello world!
Howdy world!
```

However, when trying to read this same file using Perl's [core `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip), it doesn't get past the first original file. Here is the result:

```
./my_zcat greetings.txt.gz
Hello world!
```

Here is the code for `my_zcat`:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);

my $file_name = shift;

my $fh = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($file_name) or die $GunzipError;

while (defined(my $line = readline $fh))
{
    print $line;
}
```

If I totally decompress the files before creating a new gzipped file, I don't have this problem:

```
zcat hello.txt.gz howdy.txt.gz | gzip > greetings_via_zcat.txt.gz
./my_zcat greetings_via_zcat.txt.gz
Hello world!
Howdy world!
```

So, what is the difference between `greetings.txt.gz` and `greetings_via_zcat.txt.gz` and why might `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` work correctly with `greetings.txt.gz`?

Based on this [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005155), I'm guessing that `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` messes up because of the metadata between the files. But, since `greetings.txt.gz` is a valid Gzip file, I would expect `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` to work.

My workaround for now will be piping from `zcat` (which of course doesn't help Windows users much):

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $file_name = shift;

open(my $fh, '-|', "zcat $file_name");

while (defined(my $line = readline $fh))
{
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: For reference, this question has also been posted to the module's bug tracker: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=119184

Comment: @melpomene Ticket marked as resolved since it is documented in [IO::Compress](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-Compress/lib/IO/Compress/FAQ.pod#Dealing-with-concatenated-gzip-files) to use the `MultiStream` option to deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered explicitly in the IO::Compress FAQ section [Dealing with concatenated gzip files](http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/IO-Compress-2.069/lib/IO/Compress/FAQ.pod#Dealing_with_concatenated_gzip_files). Basically you just have to include the **MultiStream** option when you construct the IO::Uncompress::Gunzip object.

Here is a [definition of the **MultiStream** option](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Uncompress::Gunzip#MultiStream-0-1):

> **`MultiStream => 0|1`**
>
> If the input file/buffer contains multiple
>   compressed data streams, this option will uncompress the whole lot as
>   a single data stream.
>
> Defaults to 0.

So your code needs this change

```
my $fh = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($file_name, MultiStream => 1) or die $GunzipError;
```

Comment: That is perfect. I'm laughing out loud right now, because I remember searching for `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` and skipping over hits to `IO::Compress` documentation because that was a "different" module.