# How to concatenate many files using their basenames?

Tags: bash, loops, concatenation

I study genetic data from 288 fish samples (Fish_one, Fish_two ...)
I have four files per fish, each with a different suffix.
eg. for sample_name Fish_one:

```
file 1 = "Fish_one.1.fq.gz"
file 2 = "Fish_one.2.fq.gz"
file 3 = "Fish_one.rem.1.fq.gz"
file 4 = "Fish_one.rem.2.fq.gz"
```

I would like to apply the following concatenate instructions to all my samples, using maybe a text file containing a list of all the sample_name, that would be provided to a loop?

```
cp sample_name.1.fq.gz sample_name.fq.gz 
cat sample_name.2.fq.gz >> sample_name.fq.gz
cat sample_name.rem.1.fq.gz >> sample_name.fq.gz
cat sample_name.rem.2.fq.gz >> sample_name.fq.gz
```

In the end, I would have only one file per sample, ideally in a different folder. 
I would be very grateful to receive a bit of help on this one, even though I'm sure the answer is quite simple for a non-novice!

Many thanks,

Noé

Comment: Related to this question: [Fast Concatenation of Multiple GZip Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8005114/8344060)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to apply the following concatenate instructions to all my
>   samples, using maybe a text file containing a list of all the
>   sample_name, that would be provided to a loop?

In the first place, the name of the `cat` command is mnemonic for "concatentate".  It accepts multiple command-line arguments naming sources to concatenate together to the standard output, which is exactly what you want to do.  It is poor form to use a `cp` and three `cat`s where a single `cat` would do.

In the second place, although you certainly could use a file of name stems to drive the operation you describe, it's likely that you don't need to go to the trouble to create or maintain such a file.  Globbing will probably do the job satisfactorily.  As long as there aren't any name stems that need to be excluded, then, I'd probably go with something like this:

```
for f in *.rem.1.fq.gz; do
  stem=${f%.rem.1.fq.gz}
  cat "$stem".{1,2,rem.1,rem.2}.fq.gz > "${other_dir}/${stem}.fq.gz"
done
```

That recognizes the groups present in the current working directory by the members whose names end with `.rem.1.fq.gz`.  It extracts the common name stem from that member's name, then concatenates the four members to the correspondingly-named output file in the directory identified by `${other_dir}`.  It relies on brace expansion to form the arguments to `cat`, so as to minimize code and (IMO) improve clarity.